# how to undo my RAID 0 setup while preserving data?

Tags: windows-xp, raid, raid-0, disk-cloning, data-migration

I currently have a RAID 0 setup with 2 drives with a single partition which holds my OS on it. Now I want to take one of those drives out and put them into another computer. But I want to keep my OS and all the files on the partition and move onto 1 drive.

I'm only using 144 GB of my RAID which consists of two 250 GB drives so there's no concern that the data won't fit.

I'm guessing the way to go is make a clone of my OS partition, disassemble the RAID, and then restore the partition to my drive of choice. The partition is NTFS, and I have both an internal 500GB disk and a 500GB external which could serve as a bridge for the disk image.

My question is what tools exist for this? And what are the implications with the MBR considering its my boot partition?

OS is Windows XP.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a partition "image" backup rather than a clone to move the installation to another non raid hard drive, SuperUser is full of many recommendations for drive image softwares, use the SU search function. Since you did not mention your OS, I cannot give an MBR repair answer.

Comment: Just briefly what's the difference between "image" and "clone"? I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: Clone means to make an exact duplicate of the entire drive all partitions and is done on the fly from one drive to the target drive, image is similar but you can select any or all partitions and the image is stored as a file and can be restored to any drive at a later date.